# relationship between spark driver and application WRT to recovery

Tags: java, apache-spark

according to spark documentation a spark application entails a driver program, which is coordinated by the SparkContext. [1]

I have been trying to implement a custom recovery mode for Spark and I have found out that during the recovery process, Spark persists and reads 3 types of information ApplicationInfo, DriverInfo and WorkerInfo. [2]

I have 2 questions.

1. Doesn't an application and it's driver constitute a one-to-one mapping? Can an application have multiple drivers or different drivers  before and after recovery?
2. What is the purpose of isolating ApplicationInfo and DriverInfo?

[1] http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

[2] https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/master/Master.scala#L521